# An unhandled exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' occurred in Unknown Module. occurred

Tags: .net-core, odata

I receive the following error in a .net core 2.2 running odata 7.1.0.
Error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException'
>   occurred in Unknown Module. occurred

The error seems to be triggered by the countdistinct function.  Otherwise the application seems to be working fine.  When the error occurs the application stops.

This works

> ```
> http://localhost:5000/odata/Uploads?$skip=0&$top=10&$count=true&$apply=groupby((uploadStatus))
> ```

This causes the error

> ```
> http://localhost:5000/odata/Uploads?$skip=0&$top=10&$count=true&$apply=groupby((uploadStatus),aggregate(uploadID%20with%20countdistinct%20as%20total))
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded the version of odata and the error went away.